# Sequelize associations

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am working on a Typescript Sequelize project, where my `/models/index.ts` file has the following "import all models in this directory" function:

```
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file);
        var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        console.log('here');
        // NOTE: you have to change from the original property notation to
        // index notation or tsc will complain about undefined property.
        db[model['name']] = model;
    });
```

I then have models structured like this `/models/user.ts`:

```
export default function defineUser(sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define<UserInstance, UserAttributes>('User', {
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: { isEmail: true }
    },
    password: Sequelize.STRING
  });
  return User;
};
```

However, I cannot then import a model from one file to another unable to do something like:

```
import * as User from './user'
// ... 
// definition of job model
// ...
Job.hasOne(User);
```

As I get `Argument of type 'typeof "~/models/job-response"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model<any, any>'.` and then:

> ~/node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:95
>   [1]       throw new Error(this.name + '.' + Utils.lowercaseFirst(Type.toString()) + ' called with something that\'s not an instance of Sequelize.Model');
>   [1]       ^
>   [1]
>   [1] Error: Job.function (srcModel, targetModel, options) {
>   [1]   Association.call(this);
>   [1]
>   [1] } called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model
>   [1]     at Model.hasOne (~\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:95:13)

How should I access a model instance such that it can be passed to the `hasMany()` or `hasOne()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

After your model registration loop runs, all of your models will be available on `db.models`, keyed by name. You can therefore, in that same file or in a separate one, do the following:

```
db.models.Job.hasOne(db.models.User)
```

I find defining relationships in a separate file convenient because if you want to define both sides of the relationship (i.e. belongsTo/hasMany) then you have to do so anyway (to avoid circular dependencies)